# Need help to design a UI using Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new in using Jetpack compose. How can I design the following UI using compose where the top half background is in deep-blue color and the bottom half is in white color?
Thanks in advance!

[image: banner.png]

I was trying to do so, but my result is not expected. A jetpack composable function with compose code is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in many different ways. I think the simplest one is to draw Rectangles behind your Composable using `Modifier.drawBehind{}`

```
fun Modifier.drawTwoColors(
    topColor: Color,
    bottomColor: Color
) = this.then(
    Modifier.drawBehind {

        val width = size.width
        val height = size.height

        drawRect(
            color = topColor,
            size = Size(width, height / 2)
        )

        drawRect(
            color = bottomColor,
            topLeft = Offset(0f, height / 2),
            size = Size(width, height / 2)
        )
    }
)
```

Usage

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .drawTwoColors(Color.Blue, Color.White)
) {

}
```

This is for even division of height. When you wish to have different ratio of top and bottom colors add 2 params and draw rectangles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code if you don't want to scroll blue part:

```
val gradient = Brush.linearGradient(
    listOf(Color.Blue.copy(0.2f), Color.White),
    start = Offset(0.0f, 50.0f),
    end = Offset(0.0f, 500.0f)
)

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .zIndex(0f)
            .background(gradient)
    )
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.zIndex(1f).fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        item {
            (0..50).forEach {
                Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .border(1.dp, color = ColorPrimary.copy(0.5f))
                    .background(Color.Yellow.copy(0.3f)),
                    contentAlignment = Center) {
                    Text(text = "Hello", modifier = Modifier.padding(50.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Else you can try this code if you want to enable scrolling in blue part:

```
val gradient = Brush.linearGradient(
    listOf(Color.Blue.copy(0.2f), Color.White),
    start = Offset(0.0f, 50.0f),
    end = Offset(0.0f, 500.0f)
)

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        item {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .height(150.dp)
                    .background(gradient)
            )
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize().offset(y= -(150.dp)),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ){
                (0..50).forEach { _ ->
                    Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
                        .wrapContentSize()
                        .border(1.dp, color = ColorPrimary.copy(0.5f))
                        .background(Color.Yellow.copy(0.3f)),
                        contentAlignment = Center) {
                        Text(text = "Hello", modifier = Modifier.padding(50.dp))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the both code but didn't get the exact result I wanted. Thanks anyways.